# Match nodes without labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to write a CYPHER query that returns only those nodes that do not have labels attached to them? 
I tried:

```
match (n:) return n
```

`Invalid input ')': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 10)
    "match (n:) return n"
              ^`

Comment: What about relations with no label?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Neo4j < 2.3:

```
MATCH n
WHERE length(labels(n)) = 0
RETURN n
```

In Neo4j >= 2.3:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE size(labels(n)) = 0
RETURN n
```